# How can I add color boxes to SELECT or to CHECKBOX?

Tags: html

I want to make selections more visual for colors. For example I want a way to add either an HTML select menu or checkbox to select color.

(blue color square) - Blue
(white color square) - White
(red color square) - Red.

Is it possible to do with select menu? If not whats best way to do it with checkboxes? stylize each one differently with CSS? Or add an image in front of it?

Any code samples or links appreciated, thx.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color

Comment: @jdabtieu close but they would be able to choose only several colors. not any color. like a checkbox or dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only looking for a few colors instead of the whole range, it's probably best to build your own input. We're going to want:

1. `input[type=radio]` to select the color
2. Labels for the inputs containing the label and color

To do this, we can do something like this

```html
<form>
  <div class="colorChoice">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="#ff0000" id="select-red">
    <label for="select-red"><div class="bg-red"></div> Red</label>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Each div contains the HTML for each color selection: an input with the value equal to the color's hex code (although you could change this to whatever you want) and a label with a color box and the associated color name.

To create the color boxes, we can set the size and background color of the divs. Doing CSS is probably best, it's wasteful to load images that really aren't necessary.

```css
.colorChoice label div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bg-red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
...
```

An advantage of this is that the `bg-*` classes are not just limited to this form - it can also be applied to other elements that need background colors.

```css
.colorChoice label div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.bg-red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.bg-green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}

.bg-blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}

.bg-black {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="colorChoice">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="#ff0000" id="select-red">
    <label for="select-red"><div class="bg-red"></div> Red</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colorChoice">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="#00ff00" id="select-green">
    <label for="select-green"><div class="bg-green"></div> Green</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colorChoice">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="#0000ff" id="select-blue">
    <label for="select-blue"><div class="bg-blue"></div> Blue</label>
  </div>
  <div class="colorChoice">
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="#000000" id="select-black">
    <label for="select-black"><div class="bg-black"></div> Black</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to use checkboxes instead, you can replace `name="color" value="..."` with just `name="..."` and change the input types from radio to checkbox.